# How check why I can't send xml file using eBay API?

Tags: ebay-api

I am sending xml files using Bulk Sell and I have success on start processing file but job status is failed:

> Failed: the Bulk Data Exchange job has not completed successfully, due to incorrect data format, request errors, or Bulk Data Exchange API errors.

I checked my xml code is not hidden chars in ansi etc. Maybe i need add more requeried files. Or maybe someone knows some tools to check XML format on ebay

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Header>
    <Version>1019</Version>
    <SiteID>UK</SiteID>
  </Header>
<AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <ErrorLanguage>en_GB</ErrorLanguage>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <Version>1019</Version>
  <Item>
    <Title>My ebay title</Title>
    <Description>Test description</Description>
    <PrimaryCategory>
      <CategoryID>42899</CategoryID>
    </PrimaryCategory>
    <StartPrice>96.00</StartPrice>
    <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
    <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
    <Country>GB</Country>
    <Currency>GBP</Currency>
    <DispatchTimeMax>2</DispatchTimeMax>
    <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
    <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
    <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
    <PayPalEmailAddress>abc@abc.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
    <PictureDetails>
    <GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
      <PictureURL>link to pictures</PictureURL>
    </PictureDetails>
    <PostalCode>abc def</PostalCode>
    <ProductListingDetails>
      <BrandMPN>
        <Brand>New brand</Brand>
        <MPN>ASM/KKD</MPN>
      </BrandMPN>
    </ProductListingDetails>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <ReturnPolicy>
      <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
      <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_14</ReturnsWithinOption>
      <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
    </ReturnPolicy>
    <Site>UK</Site>
  </Item>
</AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
</BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you haven't set your data format (REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT) to JSON, it may be expecting another format to the one you are sending. Basing this  from the error responce you posted "due to incorrect data format".

Comment: how can set this format in this XML header ? i cant find this in ebay api doc